# rogue null pointer in a binary search tree when adding strings

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

working on homework, here's the code:

```
public void insert(E value){
        Node addative= new Node(value, null, null);
        Node current=this.root;
        if(current==null){
            this.root = addative;
            size++;
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("root is: "+root.value+" value is: "+value);
        while(true){
            //System.out.println("current is currently: "+current.value);
            if(null==current.lesser)System.out.println("lesser is null");
            else System.out.println("lesser is: "+current.lesser.value);
            if(null==current.greater)System.out.println("greater is null");
            else System.out.println("greater is: "+current.greater.value);

            //if slot is empty and addative belongs here
            if(current.lesser==null&&current.value.compareTo(addative.value)>0){
                System.out.println("was added lesser");
                current.lesser=addative;
                break;
            }

            //if slot is empty and addative belongs here
            if(current.greater==null&&current.value.compareTo(addative.value)<=0){
                System.out.println("was added greater");
                current.greater=addative;
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("here");

            //no valid empty slots ergo continue along tree
            if(current.value.compareTo(addative.value)>0)current=current.lesser;
            if(current.value.compareTo(addative.value)<=0)current=current.greater;
        }
        size++;
        System.out.println("next word");
    }
```

Here's the print out:

> root is: tangerines value is: skeptics
>   lesser is null
>   greater is null
>   was added lesser
>   next word
>   root is: tangerines value is: wombats
>   lesser is: skeptics
>   greater is null
>   was added greater
>   next word
>   root is: tangerines value is: valeting
>   lesser is: skeptics
>   greater is: wombats
>   here
>   lesser is null
>   greater is null
>   was added lesser
>   next word
>   root is: tangerines value is: bubble
>   lesser is: skeptics
>   greater is: wombats
>   here
>   lesser is null
>   greater is null
>   was added lesser
>   next word
>   root is: tangerines value is: pigeonhole
>   lesser is: skeptics
>   greater is: wombats
>   here
>   lesser is: bubble
>   greater is null
>   here

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at BinarySearchTree.insert(BinarySearchTree.java:35)
    at BinarySearchTree.main(BinarySearchTree.java:178)
```

Line 35 says:

```
if(null==current.lesser)System.out.println("lesser is null");
```

am I trying to null reference wrong? I don't understand how this can add 5-10 words and work, but on the 11th time it errors out.

Comment: what do you mean by 'am I trying to null reference wrong?'

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `null` to your current here:

```
// before adding 'pigeonhole':
             tangerines
    skeptics           wombats
bubble     null    valeting   null
```

Now, when on 'skeptics', `"skeptics".compareTo("pigeonhole") < 0`, so you set `current = current.greater`, i.e. `current = null`. On the next iteration you call `current.lesser`, which results in an NPE.

The problem here is that you yourself say 'no valid empty slots' and assign them right after that. You should change your logic so that when you didn't perform insertion on a current level, the `current` assignment is based not just on a `compareTo` result, but on entries' `null` status as well. E.g.:

```
// pigeonhole < skeptics, hence
if (current > addative && current.lesser != null) {
    current = current.lesser;
}
// and something like that for the 'greater' case
```

Anyway, you should've used good old pencil-and-paper debugging for this, since this bug can be easily uncovered if you try to manually reproduce the steps. Actually, you should use this method *before* you start to code an algorithm because it seems that formal assessment of the correctness of your implementations isn't your strongest side yet, and writing down every possible step of your program is the best way to train that skill.

Comment: yea i pulled out the pencil and paper and it didn't uncover the bug. thanks though for the input  and yes that was the bug. took me like 3 hours to uncover. our teacher has been having skip using else statements when possible and it's leading to more bugs in my coding. thanks again though.

Comment: Actually, another possible reason of such a code might be that you mix two styles. If I understand correctly, you study something like Algorithms/Data Structures 101, so they should've told you about the recursion already. As the tree itself is a  recursive data structure, I'd suggest you to rewrite your while-loop using recursion. This will greatly simplify your code, which will make it less bug-prone, more concise and maintainable overall.

Comment: psh, don't I wish. I asked in class while he was showing this if we could run it recursively and he said no. he's been real picky lately of how we write our code. I would have preferred to write it recursively because the beginning of the semester was all recursion and I got used to it.